# How to generate file using GsonFormat plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-import

Here is the link
http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=9htuhtcb4ymusd73d4z6jxcj

and I want to generate a file using GsonFormat plugin which is already installed on Android Studio.
I'm using windows 7

Comment: I got it and it is alt+insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps:

Android studio > Help > find actions

type "Plugin" in search bar > Search in repositories

install the required plugin. That's it.

Answer (score 10):

1. Install GsonFormat plugin
2. Generate a new class.
3. in this new class, inside the body of the class, right click.
4. in the menu that opens choose Generate.
5. in the new menu that open choose GsonFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

And it is alt+insert